# How to get current ringtone in Android?

Tags: android, uri, ringtone, android-audiomanager

I have found lots of examples how to get default ringtone. Something like that:

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),  alert);
         ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
         ringtone.play();
```

But I want to get the actual current ringtone, that was set by the user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was struggling with this issue as well, so the solution is:

```
Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), defaultRingtoneUri);
```

Comment: what is `getActivity()` ?

Comment: The current `Activity` instance, which is used in `Fragment`s, if you are in an `Activity`, use `YourActivity.this` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've also searched a lot for your problem which I also had. 
At last got solution from this itself.

Use below code in the button for ringtone intent.

```
public void pickRingtone(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method.stub

        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Ringtone");

    // for existing ringtone
        Uri urie = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, urie);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
}
```

Comment: This still didn't answer my question. I just simply want to grab a URI for the currently selected ringtone (by a user). I don't need any Ringtone Picker or anything like that. I just need to get a uri and play it when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the extension of dgabor's answer.
Just add `defaultRingtone.play();` to play the ringtone.

```
Uri defaultRintoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), defaultRintoneUri);
defaultRingtone.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by `Alexander The Great` was correct. But, I simplified it.

```
Uri currentRingtonUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI);
```

Comment: This won't work, because RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri accepts only INT parameter, while  RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI is a String.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
uri default_ringtone_uri = Settings.System.DeFAULT_RINGTONE_URI

Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri).play();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.